# How to view the Unix command that Ansible runs?

Tags: unix, ansible

I have an Ansible task:

```
- name: Ensure Gluster volume is mounted.
  mount:
    name: "{{ mount_dir }}"
    src: "{{ inventory_hostname }}:{{ brick_name }}"
    fstype: glusterfs
    opts: "defaults,_netdev"
    state: mounted
```

It fails with output:

```
fatal: [remotehost.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "invocation": {"module_args": {"dump": null, "fstab": "/etc/fstab", "fstype": "glusterfs", "name": "ssl", "opts": "defaults,_netdev", "passno": null, "src": "remotehost.com:/craik/clm/ssl", "state": "mounted"}, "module_name": "mount"}, "msg": "Error mounting ssl: Mount failed. Please check the log file for more details.\n"}
```

Is it possible to see the actual Unix command that Ansible is translating the mount task to?

For example:

```
mount -t glusterfs remotehost.com:/craik/clm/ssl /srv/gluster/ssl
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ansible uses Python scripts to perform its actions (it might call external programs from the Python, but if there is no necessity, it doesn't).

You can cause Ansible to leave the actual script which was run on the target machine by adding `ANSIBLE_KEEP_REMOTE_FILES=1` to the environment on the control machine before executing `ansible-playbook`.

For example if you run:

```
ANSIBLE_KEEP_REMOTE_FILES=1 ansible-playbook playbook.yml -vvv
```

You will see in the transcript something like:

```
PUT /var/folders/nw/2vnhg_gj77v_cyfv0p1vdfj80000gn/T/tmpidULyi TO /home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1484137690.32-255077767492235/mount.py
```

Then if you open the `mount.py` you can verify the actual code (you might also be able to re-run it).

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't see the command without source code modification.

`mount` module's [source code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/system/mount.py) suggests that it:

- write `'%(src)s %(name)s %(fstype)s %(opts)s %(dump)s %(passno)s\n'` to fstab
- execute `mount <name>`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running ansible with the -vvvv flag? 
That enables verbosity, and it usually shows you what command is being run.

It is usually hidden somewhere in the output, but it is there.

Comment: I have indeed but it doesn't actually display the command that it tried to execute...

Comment: Can you post the output?